# Badge in BottomNavigationView is not changing color after theme change

Tags: java, android, themes

I have implemented theme change logic in my Android app. Unfortunately when I am changing theme and call recreate function badge in BottomNavigationView is not changing background color, please find my code:

```
    private void setBadge(Integer newMessageCount) {
        BadgeDrawable badge = bottomNav.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.nav_messages);
        badge.setNumber(newMessageCount);
        badge.setBackgroundColor(ThemeColors.getColor(this, R.attr.secondaryColor));
        badge.setBadgeTextColor(ThemeColors.getColor(this, R.attr.secondaryTextColor));
    }
```

```
public class ThemeColors {

    public static @ColorInt
    int getColor(Context context, int attrColor) {
        return ContextCompat.getColor(context, getColorResourceId(context, attrColor));
    }

    public static int getColorResourceId(Context context, int attrColor) {
        TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
        context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(attrColor, typedValue, true);
        return typedValue.resourceId;
    }
}
```

Could you please let me know why background color is not changing?
Regards

Comment: How do you getOrCreate this badge? What is it anyway?

Comment: I'm calling getOrCreateBadge from onCreate method